# Can I increment page views as users scroll to sections containing new images in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, page, page-views

I have a page which has multiple images, each image appears per fold.  Using google analytics is it possible to increment the page views counter?

So let's say if 3 images on a page the page has total 4 views if a user views all 3 image.

```
1 for page view + 3 For images = 4
```

Comment: You could probably track an event if the user clicks on the image or event if it scrolls to it. But as far as I know, a page view is a Page view so if you want to increment page view counter you probably will have to create different pages for each image and link them on page 1.

Comment: So your saying event is the thing that will perfectly capture the scrolling? is it possible to increment counter on each image view on a page? i mean how many images viewed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a javascript to send an event to google analytics on viewing of the image.
refer https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: Events don't increment page views.   You should either update this answer with something that answers the question or explain better how events might help anyway.